# Latitude Checkout API returns string(0) "" using curl

Tags: php, api, curl, payment-gateway

Iam trying to integrate Latitude checkout in my prestashop site. I have implemented API using curl.
It always returns string(0) "". And also showing 400 Bad Request in header. Iam expecting a redirect url as output .
This is the code i tried

```
$url = "https://api.test.latitudefinancial.com/v1/applybuy-checkout-service/purchase";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU6bGZzbXNfXzI2NWM4N2QyNjAxYTQzNWQ5YzdmZDlkZDM5MzEyNDI4",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{"merchantId":"directnetuser","isTest":true,"merchantReference":"102","amount":550.00,"currency":"AUD","promotionReference":"2012","customer":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","phone":"0400000000","email":"john.doe@email.com"},"shippingAddress":{"name":"John Doe","line1":"100 Spencer Street","line2":"tttt","city":"Melbourne","postcode":"3000","state":"VIC","countryCode":"AU","phone":"0400000000"},"billingAddress":{"name":"John Doe","line1":"100 Spencer Street","line2":"tttt","city":"Melbourne","postcode":"3000","state":"VIC","countryCode":"AU","phone":"0400000000"},"orderLines":[{"name":"Echo Fit Compression Short","productUrl":"","sku":"WSH07-28-Black","quantity":5,"unitPrice":100.00,"amount":500.00,"requiresShipping":true,"isGiftCard":false},{"name":"Short","productUrl":"","sku":"ACW-24-Black","quantity":2,"unitPrice":150.00,"amount":300.00,"requiresShipping":true,"isGiftCard":false}],"merchantUrls":{"cancel":"https://directnet.latitudecheckout.com/purchase/checkout","complete":"https://directnet.latitudecheckout.com/purchase/verify"},"totalShippingAmount":50.00,"platformType":"direct","platformVersion":"0.0.1"}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: Is your primary problem how to correct the HTTP status code of 400 - Bad Request?

Comment: Yeah, I want to get an array  as output by correcting this issue.

Comment: I have tried without Content-Type: application/json . Now it returns the code 303 see other . Can anyone help me to find what this status code indicates?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two line before curl execute

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

then

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```